# Large matrix multiplication in Excel

Tags: excel, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a correlation matrix (say matrix A) in Excel with about 4,200 rows and the same number of columns, which is quite large for the everyday Excel user.

I also have another matrix (B) with the same number of rows and 1 column. For each row `i` of the matrix A, I want to multiply its element `Aij` by the elements `Bi1` and `Bj1`, and have the sum of the elements in each row of A after that multiplication.

That sum of rows is what is relevant, the matrices are not. That could be easily achieved with formulas, but with that amount of data the file becomes too large to be manipulated.

Are there any better ways of going about this in Excel?

Comment: While Excel is very convenient, it's not a great "Big" data tool. Tools like Matlab, "R", Gnu Octave, Scilab, Sage etc. may be better, IF you have the time and inclination to learn them. That said, the above looks like a possibility in VBA, But to get decent performance I believe you will need to pull the values into arrays in memory and manipulate them there, which is an order of magnitude faster than "plain" VBA. The idea is you read the sheet Once, into memory (an Array), process it there, and then write it back Once, to the spreadsheet. cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Comment: An alternative language is Julia, which is almost as user friendly as Mallab, and almost as fasts as C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not rule out using a formula.  I have a Ryzen 7 2700x on 16G of ram, with Excel O365. I ran a few methods on a 4200 x 4200 floating point sample and got surprising runtimes.  I tried a few different approaches.  The fastest was this.  I *think* this gets you the result you wanted (requires O365):

```
=LET(
matrix,MMULT(SmallTable,TRANSPOSE(SmallTable))*BigTable,
BYROW(matrix,LAMBDA(r,SUM(r)))
)
```

I named the 4,200 x 1 array `SmallTable` and the 4,200 x 4,200 array `BigTable`.

And I get < 3 second completion times.

Comment: This does the computation, and btw is an interesting use of formulas, but doesn't address the issue with the file becoming too large. Didn't know about 'BYROW', thanks.

Comment: VERY interesting. Thanks Max R, I learned something today. Saved it too.

Comment: @Rafael The breakthrough for me was realizing that I didn't have to use multiple INDEX() functions to "fetch" Bi1 and Bj1 for all 16 mill values.  And using the LET() approach allows me to create that B matrix ONE time.  That allows me to eliminate 32 or 48 million INDEX() calls.  As for worksheet size, what is the column growth trend been?  You're only a quarter of the way to 16,000+ column limit.